# Best low-cost microcontroller (that can be programmed using Python) for computer vision?

Tags: microcontroller, python, imageprocessing, micropython

I have been researching for many days and haven't found a microcontroller that fits my needs.

I want a microcontroller that:

- Is cheap (I want to make this into a product that can be around $20-40)
- Can be programmed using Python because I have made a desktop app that uses Python that I want to run on a microcontroller
- A camera can be used with the microcontroller
- Is good at image processing and can handle live video streaming because that is used in my Python program

I am asking for a lot and there is probably not a microcontroller out there that meets these criteria but anything close to this would be significant.

Comment: You are correct: a microcontroller won't do this. Your only choice is a Beaglebone or RPI unless you have extensive hardware development skills to implement a board for an application processor.

Comment: I don't have specific recommendations, but "good at image processing" probably spans a few orders of magnitude worth of processing power, so you might want to try and narrow that down with a rough estimate of MUL/s, FLOPs, or whatever needed.

Comment: @jsotola I will delete my question in a bit and ask on a specific microcontroller.

Comment: you can edit this one ... there isn't any answer that would be invalidated by an edit

Comment: Deleting questions indiscriminately  can get you suspended – it’s not considered good form. Instead, edit the question to address the deficiencies pointed out in the comments. Generally though, if you develop for a GPU on a PC using Python, you’ll need something that has PC-like power. So not a microcontroller but a Linux SoC, some of which come with an FPGA as well. Not even powerful micros like RP2040 can do this unless the image size is tiny like 128x128.

Comment: The entire electronics supply chain right now is in chaos and shambles. It seems like a Raspberry Pi would be a good way to go for ease of development. But they are presently unobtainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, computer vision is too computationally intensive to run on a microcontroller. The vast majority probably won't even have enough ram to store 1 frame.

However, there are special cameras that have a processor built in, specifically for computer vision. Something like this will probably fit the bill: [OpenMV Cam H7](https://openmv.io/)

And another one: [Pixy2](https://pixycam.com/pixy2/)

Comment: Another one: [Jevois smart machine vision camera](http://jevois.org/) – a Linux computer with tensor flow and a camera integrated in a tiny package.